# node request: saved image file is not readable

Tags: node.js, request

I am using the following library:

https://github.com/request/request

On my node server and try to download a png image from a url and write it to a file:

```
  request
.get("https://url/for/png/file")
.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
.on('response', function(response){
  console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
  console.log(response.headers['content-type']); // 'image/png'
})
.on('complete', (resp: http.IncomingMessage, body: string | Buffer) => {
  fs.writeFile(".../test.png", body, 'binary');

});
```

The main issue is that the written file is curruped (can't be opened).

If I use `pipe` instead of `on('complete'...)` at the end the written file is correct.

```
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(".../test.png"))
```

What exactly is the difference and what am I missing to be able to write the file?

Answer (score 0):

`complete` event has only one param, `IncomingMessage`

```
request.get("https://www.google.pl/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png")
.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err)
})
.on('response', function (response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode); // 200
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']); // 'image/png'
    response.on('data', function (data) {
        fs.writeFile("../test.png", data, {flag : "a+"}, function () {});
    })
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that I need to add the response headers to the binary data of the image to have it work if I don't use pipe?

Comment: It's strange because this code works for me. What version of node and request do u have?